# QDockWidget in QStackWidget

Tags: c++, qt, designer, qdockwidget

I have a stackWidget with 2 pages.
In the page 1, I have 2 QTreeWidget (one on the left, one on the right).

I would like to be able to modify the width of my trees in the same principle that the DockWidget. The problem is I can't use the DockWidget only in 1 page of the stackWidget.

Does someone has an idea to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a [`QSplitter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsplitter.html). In the Qt Designer you can also find the in the tool bar. Just click on the widget that should have such a `QSplitter` layout and the click on the tool button.